# Why does null keep coming back when getting nodeValue even though it displays properly?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, nodevalue

This is driving me nuts. I'm inserting code into a page via Ajax. After the code is inserted I am running a function to grab the text of one of the DIVs and display it in another location on the page.

Can someone tell me why I keep getting a JavaScript error saying that `currentText` is null, even though the text displays properly in the other location in the page??

```
var currentText = document.getElementById("current-text"),
updatedTextHere = document.getElementById("updated-text-here");

updatedTextHere.innerHTML = currentText.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

This is the code it's grabbing the text value from, which is inserted into the main page via Ajax:

```
<div id="current-text" class="hide">January 1, 2011</div>
```

UPDATE:

Here's how it looks:

```
getDate = function () {
    var currentText = document.getElementById("current-text"),
    updatedTextHere = document.getElementById("updated-text-here");

    updatedTextHere.innerHTML = currentText.firstChild.nodeValue;
},

htmlready = function () {
    myDiv.innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
    getDate();
},
```

Comment: Why not just use innerHTML? So updatedTextHere.innerHTML = currentText.innerHTML; No idea why it doesn't work though. Really strange.

Comment: It would help to see the ajax method you are using for creating this element.

Comment: I've updated my post that contains an example of how it's being called after the Ajax is inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is that `firstChild` isn't a node of `currentText`. Your `nodeValue` doesn't have a value because it doesn't exist. You should use `innerHTML` or `textContent` instead.

Change to...

```
updatedTextHere.innerHTML = currentText.firstChild.textContent; // or innerHTML
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to correct it because there isn't a way to pass a callback into the method in my JS Lib for Ajax. Can you see anyway to fix it with the updated code I've provided above?

Comment: Actually after looking at your updated example, your scope was fine. See my revised answer above for your solution.